# Developing a decoder for CANbus / J1939

Tags: can-bus, j1939

So, I have been told that I will need to integrate some CANbus / J1939 output into a Windows app, and I know nothing about it.

There are vague plans to use an off the shelf device, and capture the output from that.

Since this seems to be a 7 layer model, I am presuming that I need to decode layer 3.

And, at that, I am stuck.

Any links to the correct spec? Other information? Existing free code which will take that data, parse it and stuff it into a MySql database? If there a central site, with forum, where I can better direct such questions? Any good books? Any same data for me to practise decoding? I am drowning in google results, but none greatly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look here http://www.ixxat.com/sae_j1939_api_en.html?navigation=28834, this is a proprietary API.

Comment: Thanks!!  Any other help? That's great as it is, but it seems like you know hte subject, so any hints are welcome